# AuthorizationCode to request google a accesstoken oauth2 with java

Tags: oauth-2.0

I already have the AuthorizationCode via returnurl, but i cant use it to generate a toke to talk with google api in java

Comment: Please see the following link on how to ask a good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

i solved my question getting the credentials via a java apllication using the key.json

```
            credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("key.json"));
            credentials = credentials.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow"));

            credentials.refreshIfExpired();
            AccessToken token = credentials.getAccessToken();
```

after that i use the resttemplate to call and detectintent